# JQuery / JS - One selector for multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker, timepicker

Is it possible to assign one selector to multiple input fields?

I'm using a timepicker (jQuery-UI) to assign the timepicker to an input field. But I noticed, that I have to create a selector for each of my input fields. Huge overload, isn't it?

Selector:

```
$('#timepicker').timepicker({controlType: 'select',timeFormat: 'HH:mm'});
```

Input fields:

```
<div class="large-1 columns"><input type="text" id="timepicker" placeholder="Start"></div>
<div class="large-1 columns"><input type="text" id="timepicker" placeholder="End"></div>
```

times 6x
So I have 14 possible timepicker inputs.

Is this possible?

Comment: It is possible, but remember that IDs are unique, so jQuery will only select the first element of that ID and ignore the rest. Try using a class instead, and then for your jQuery selector use `$('.timepicker').timepicker(...)`

Comment: Class is the better way, but if you still insist on using it on IDs.. try $('#id1, #id2...., #idn'). event()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be using same ID for multiple inputs. Use class instead, ID should be unique.
This is how to do it with class.

```
$('.timepicker').timepicker({controlType: 'select',timeFormat: 'HH:mm'});
```

And the html

```
<div class="large-1 columns"><input type="text" class="timepicker" placeholder="Start"></div>
<div class="large-1 columns"><input type="text" class="timepicker" placeholder="End"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like that:

```
$(":input").timepicker({controlType: 'select',timeFormat: 'HH:mm'});
```